# How to move elements when drop down is expanded

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a task where I am required that after the drop down is expanded the elements below the dropdown should not get hidden.

They should move down as the drop down expands and move up as the drop down unexpand.

Is this possible?

I have a sample code below:

```
<select id="test">
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
<option value="c">C</option>
<option value="d">D</option>
<option value="e">E</option>
</select>
<div>abc</div>
```

I want div "**abc**" to move down when the dropdown is **expanded** so that it doesnt get hidden behind dropdown options.

Once the dropdown **unexpand**,I want div **"abc"** to come back to its original position.

Comment: yes... no... probaly... maybe... Idon't know... all this depends on your situation and if you don't show us your code I doubt you get a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you don't want the elements hidden behind the dropdown then you have two ways to go..

1. Attach an onClick event to the dropdown to change the min-height css attribute of the box below (which contains the other elements) or the container of the select box from 'auto' to the needed amount of pixels.
2. Implement a dropdown in CSS with divs/ul showing and hiding the children elements. You can take the same approach as a website does dropdown menu in their headers. This will push all content down.

Comment: I will go with the answer above :)