# Jquery Select Box Overlap on expand

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, slidedown

I have 2 select Boxes, they are stacked on top of each other, when one expands you can't see the other one behind it as it overlaps. Is there any way I can make the second box move down either using JQuery `slideDown()` and appear under the expanded content?

**Update**

i am trying to achieve the following:

[image]

I have made a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/NXDUg4l4t7).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move elements when drop down is expanded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107280/how-to-move-elements-when-drop-down-is-expanded)

Comment: That is just the basic behaviour of select boxes. Once you select a option from the top box it closes and you can see the bottom one. May I ask why you want to achieve this effect?

Comment: I see, thanks for that - i am trying to achieve the following as my image, would it be better to not use select boxes and code it using div's and toggle / slide animation?